# Inserting data in private ipfs network from outside of server throws timeout error

Tags: server, ipfs, js-ipfs

I installed private ipfs network on my server and after that i tested it with entering a file and getting it which works perfectly,now when i try to follow the same steps from my local machine,getting data is working with the url - http://{server's ip}:8080/ipfs/{hash} but when i created api on Nodejs to insert data using url - http://{server's ip}:5001 then i am getting the error of timeout,though this api is working on deploying on server and changing the server's ip to localhost.

IPFS config is as follows -

```js
{
  "API": {
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": [
        "PUT",
        "GET",
        "POST"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Addresses": {
    "API": "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/5001",
    "Announce": [],
    "Gateway": "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/8080",
    "NoAnnounce": [],
    "Swarm": [
      "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/4001",
      "/ip6/::/tcp/4001"
    ]
  },
  "Bootstrap": [
    "/ip4/{server's ip}/tcp/4001/ipfs/<peer identity hash of bootnode>"
  ],
  "Datastore": {
    "BloomFilterSize": 0,
    "GCPeriod": "1h",
    "HashOnRead": false,
    "Spec": {
      "mounts": [
        {
          "child": {
            "path": "blocks",
            "shardFunc": "/repo/flatfs/shard/v1/next-to-last/2",
            "sync": true,
            "type": "flatfs"
          },
          "mountpoint": "/blocks",
          "prefix": "flatfs.datastore",
          "type": "measure"
        },
        {
          "child": {
            "compression": "none",
            "path": "datastore",
            "type": "levelds"
          },
          "mountpoint": "/",
          "prefix": "leveldb.datastore",
          "type": "measure"
        }
      ],
      "type": "mount"
    },
    "StorageGCWatermark": 90,
    "StorageMax": "10GB"
  },
  "Discovery": {
    "MDNS": {
      "Enabled": true,
      "Interval": 10
    }
  },
  "Experimental": {
    "FilestoreEnabled": false,
    "Libp2pStreamMounting": false,
    "P2pHttpProxy": false,
    "QUIC": false,
    "ShardingEnabled": false,
    "UrlstoreEnabled": false
  },
  "Gateway": {
    "APICommands": [],
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": [
        "X-Requested-With",
        "Range"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": [
        "GET"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    "PathPrefixes": [],
    "RootRedirect": "",
    "Writable": false
  },
  "Identity": {
    "PeerID": "<peer identity hash of bootnode>"
  },
  "Ipns": {
    "RecordLifetime": "",
    "RepublishPeriod": "",
    "ResolveCacheSize": 128
  },
  "Mounts": {
    "FuseAllowOther": false,
    "IPFS": "/ipfs",
    "IPNS": "/ipns"
  },
  "Pubsub": {
    "DisableSigning": false,
    "Router": "",
    "StrictSignatureVerification": false
  },
  "Reprovider": {
    "Interval": "12h",
    "Strategy": "all"
  },
  "Routing": {
    "Type": "dht"
  },
  "Swarm": {
    "AddrFilters": null,
    "ConnMgr": {
      "GracePeriod": "20s",
      "HighWater": 900,
      "LowWater": 600,
      "Type": "basic"
    },
    "DisableBandwidthMetrics": false,
    "DisableNatPortMap": false,
    "DisableRelay": false,
    "EnableRelayHop": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does the timeout come from? Is it HTTP timeout (no response), or is go-ipfs returning timeout response?

Comment: It is HTTP timeout,giving by api i created

Comment: This sound like networking configuration error not related to IPFS. 
Perhaps you have a firewall enabled, or a NAT between client and server?

Comment: Yes,it was resolved,the tcp inbound rules for respective ports were not allowed in aws confguration